# Who opens an airliner's door first after it lands?

Tags: airline-operations

I know this is a trivial question, but since I always sit near the back of the plane, I can't see what happens up in the front. Whose responsibility is it to open the cabin door once the aircraft has pulled up to the jet bridge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the type of aircraft. But [USA today/Ask the Captain](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/cox/2016/02/07/plane-exit-door/79875252/) gives a nice explanation:

> *Question:* I was wondering what takes so long to get the exit door open after we land. Could you please go through the steps?
>
> ---
>
> *Answer:* Once the airplane arrives at the gate and is properly chocked, the captain shuts down the engines and switches off the “Fasten Seat Belt” light. The anti-collision light (this is the red blinking light on the top and bottom of the airplane) is switched off, informing ground crew that it is safe to approach the airplane.
>
> Ground crew members then begin to position the jet bridge, aligning it with the door.  Once the jet bridge is mated to the aircraft and the cover is in place, **the ground agent either opens the door or taps on it for the flight attendant to open it.** This varies depending on the type of airplane to minimize the chance for an inadvertent slide deployment.
>
> Once the door is initially opened, the ground agent assists in fully opening it and ensuring that it is locked in the open position.
>
> This is the generic procedure for most jet airliners. Regional or smaller airplanes have a slightly different procedure as their stairs are built into the door.